# How can I fetch source code from synergy using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cm-synergy

I have installed synergy plugin for Jenkins.

I want to fetch some code from synergy DB.

How can I do it using jenkins?

I have given all the details in SCM section of Jenkins like DB value, Engine, Username and password.

Comment: So what is the issue you are getting?

Comment: Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\test\workspace
[workspace] $ ccm start -d DB_Path -nogui -m -q -h Server_Name -n user_name -pw ******** -rc
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ccm" (in directory "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\test\workspace"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
 at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
 at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
 at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:773)

Comment: Is the program `ccm` in the PATH of the user with which Jenkins is running? Try printing `echo %PATH%` and see what you get in console log of this job.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the error. As I am new to Jenkins so didn't notice the option to specify ccm exe path. So I rectified this error. But next error comes as

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\Synergy\7.1\bin" (in directory "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\test\workspace"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as i stated in my comments, the reason behind the following *original* issue error was related to PATH:

```
Cannot run program "ccm" (in directory "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\test\workspace"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified...
```

For the *second* issue i.e.,

```
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\Synergy\7.1\bin" (in directory "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\test\workspace"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

it seems you have not specified the full path to the executable as shown in the above error message.

Hopefully, changing

`"C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\Synergy\7.1\bin"`

to

`"C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\Synergy\7.1\bin\executable_name.exe"`

should do the trick.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot. Can you maybe help in the next error message as -
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\Synergy\7.1\bin\ccm.exe" start -d DBPath -nogui -m -q -h ServerName -n UserName -pw ******** -rc


ccm command failed
Warning: Cannot open logfile 'C:\ \ccm_ui.log'
Warning: IBM Rational Synergy startup failed.



When I run this in cmd it runs though.

Comment: Is there something in jenkins that is stopping itself to access the synergy db. Like if it is getting called remotely.

Comment: Are you running the exact same command through command line and it's working fine?

Comment: Yes it is working fine from cmd line. Just entered the password manually.

Comment: If all your commands work fine as user 'X' from command line, then try running Jenkins with the same user. This can be achieved by going to `Run > services.msc (Enter) > Jenkins > Properties > Log On (tab) > Select user and provide credentials > Restart Jenkins`

Comment: It also worked :) Thanks a lot.. 

But How can I disable build manager role. I just want to extract the code from synergy to my workspace. Will be of great help..
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\Synergy\7.1\bin\ccm.exe" set role build_mgr
ccm command failed
Warning: 'build_mgr' is not a valid role for user

Comment: Glad it worked. :) You should raise a separate question for the current issue.

Comment: Okay .. will raise it.. Thanks.. :)

Comment: As you explained yesterday of logging in Jenkins using the same X account, so is it not picking up the credentials from the synergy plugin? Cz I practically want synergy to use a particular credential(Y) but I don't want to login in into jenkins using that(Y).

Comment: Is this related to the other question that you posted yesterday?

Comment: No, this is about "Run > services.msc (Enter) > Jenkins > Properties > Log On (tab) > Select user and provide credentials > Restart Jenkins"

The credentials that I have for accessing the synergy is in a domain from which I can't loggin into jenkins. So I want to loggin into jenkins using some other credentials and want synergy to pick the credentials that I set when I configure the synergy plugin.

Comment: There are three different things: User with which you login to Jenkins, user with which Jenkins runs & user whose credentials you are providing to Synergy plugin. All these can be different users. After understanding this, let me know what you're looking for.